# Meteor v 1.0 and Iron:Router

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Is anyone else getting the following error from Iron-Router since upgrading Meteor to version 1.0?

Please post here if you know how to resolve this issue.

> Route dispatch never rendered. Did you forget to call `this.next()` in an `onBeforeAction`?

```js
Router.map(function () {
    Router.route('profileShow', {

        waitOn: function () {
            if (Meteor.user()) {
                Meteor.subscribe('userData');
            } else {
                this.next();
            }
        },

        data: function () {
            if (Meteor.user()) {
                return {profile: Meteor.user().profile};
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There was a non backwards-compatible change in the newest version of Iron Router. The migration guide says:

> *`onRun` and `onBeforeAction` hooks now require you to call `this.next()`, and no longer take a `pause()` argument. So the default behaviour is reversed. For example, if you had:*

```js
Router.onBeforeAction(function(pause) {
  if (! Meteor.userId()) {
    this.render('login');
    pause();
  }
});
```

> *You'll need to update it to*

```js
Router.onBeforeAction(function() {
  if (! Meteor.userId()) {
    this.render('login');
  } else {
    this.next();
  }
});
```

---

[More information](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/README.md#hooks)

In your case, the by-the-book fix would be to add `this.next()` at the end of `onBeforeAction`. However, you should rather use `waitOn`:

```
waitOn: function () {
  return Meteor.subscribe("userData");
}
```

That way, you can set a `loadingTemplate` which will appear while the `userData` subscription is loading.

Comment: Just to add that it may be an onRun causing the error even if the message says it was an onBeforeAction. The error message could be better.